# How to find the weight of the heaviest path of an undirected, unweighted graph (M(d) of the graph), using adjacency matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, graph, tree

[In the image A-L is the longest path, but L-M is the heaviest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed703.jpg)
The heaviest path of the graph is the path with the most edges connected to it, for this current case the heaviest path is L-M with 19 edges: L-K, K-J, J-I, I-H, H-G, G-F, F-E, F-M, M-N, M-O, M-P, M-Q, M-R, M-S, M-T, M-U, M-V, M-W, M-X.
I am trying to create a program that will check that the inputted matrix represents a tree graph, and if it does, that returns the number of edges on the heaviest path of the graph. In other words it will return the M(d) of the graph.
For this current case the output will be the number of edges connected to L-M path which is 19.

But I can not find a way to do that. Here I created a function to find the row with the least 1s to set it as a root, but don't know how to proceed.

```
let matrix = [
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],


//find row with least 1s
function findRowWithLeastOnes(matrix_data) {
  let counter = 0;
  let row = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix_data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix_data[i].length; j++) {
      if (matrix_data[i][j] === 1) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    if (counter < matrix_data.length) {
      row = i;
      console.log(row);
      return row;
    }
  }
}
findRowWithLeastOnes(matrix);
```

Comment: You speak of "heaviest path": does that mean the graph is weighted? Is the example with only 0 and 1 a simplification?

Comment: Furthermore, the example matrix represents an undirected graph? Is this always the case? If not, can you provide an example that represents a directed (and if applicable, *weighted*) graph?

Comment: The undirected graph is always the case, that's the bad part of it.
I need to find the heaviest path of the graph, in other words the path that has the most connections, thats why I started with finding rows with the least 1s to get the root and proceed to other its connections.
0 and 1 in the matrix represent the connections between them, 1 if there is a connection, and 0 if there is no connection

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I hope you can stay around and answer questions more quickly though. Can you edit your question, to include the info that the graph is always undirected (and so the matrix is always mirrored along the main diagonal)? Can you also add in your question that you are looking for the longest path, which is the more common way to talk about it when your graph is essentially non-weighted.

Comment: Yes I will, but Im not trying to find the longest path, Im trying to find the path with the most nodes in other words the heaviest path of the graph, and number of nodes connected to that path.

Comment: I don't understand how a path with the most nodes is different from a longest path. Isn't that the same thing? The definition of the longest path in an unweighted graph is the path with the most edges. So that is the same as saying the path with the most nodes on it.

Comment: I have added an image representing a graph where the longest path is different from the heaviest one

Comment: OK, but what is then the formal definition of "heaviest" here? Do you have a reference to a definition? Or can you formulate a precise definition? I studied graph theory in detail but never came across this concept, and I'd need to know how you define and calculate the "weight" here.

Comment: So the formal definition in my studies was the M(d) of the matrix. In this case I should find the path with the most nodes and also count nodes connected to that path
The M(d) for the graph in the photo is equal to 19 with the nodes L-K, K-J, J-I, I-H, H-G, G-F, F-E, F-M, M-N, M-O, M-P, M-Q, M-R, M-S, M-T, M-U, M-V, M-W, M-X

Comment: OK, I see. Do you happen to have a reference where I can find more on this concept? Can you also edit your question, to include a formal definition?

Comment: BTW, in the question you ask for the number of nodes, but in this last comment you seem to count the number of edges, not the number of nodes. Can you tell me which you need? Or do you need a list of edges, like you did in the comment above?

Comment: Yeah I need to find the number of edges, sorry thare was a mistake.
I will try to find something about that on the internet.

Comment: Hey Trincot, can provide a solution please?)

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add the definition of heavy/heaviest (best with a reference) *in* the question, and can you provide the input in the JavaScript code for the graph you have depicted in an image, the output you get for it, and which output you should get, all inside the question?

Comment: I added the definition for the heaviest path and added the all information in the question, can you please review it?

Comment: Can you please check it now Trincot?)

Comment: You added this "definition": *"The heaviest path of the graph is the path with the most edges"*, but that is the definition of the longest path. Please, is it not possible to give a *precise* definition?

Comment: Its the path with the most edges connected to it, I gave you the example for the tree in a photo

Comment: I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following algorithm:

- Turn the matrix into an adjacency list so to avoid scanning zeroes all the time, and to have easy access to the *degree* of a node, which contributes to the weight.
- Choose any node to start with (e.g. 0) and find the heaviest path from it. We can use a depth-first search for that (for instance, using recursion). From all paths that are found, keep the heaviest. To avoid an edge being traversed back and forth, remember what the previous node was in the traversal: it should not be revisited. If there was a previous node, we should avoid counting the traversed edge twice in the sum of weights.
- Take the last node in that path: this is the node that is the furthest away from our starting node in terms of weight. This node will be an end-point of the heaviest path we are looking for.
- Use the same algorithm a second time to find the heaviest path from that node. This is the path we need.

If your question is also about determining whether a graph is a tree, you would essentially need to check there are no cycles (a depth first traversal can be used again) and that from one node all others can be reached (again depth first can serve). Maybe you'd also want to check that the graph is undirected, i.e. that the matrix is mirrored along the main diagonal.

```js
function isUndirected(matrix) {
    if (matrix.length !== matrix[0]?.length) return false; // must be square
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] !== matrix[j][i]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function isTree(matrix) {
    const visited = Array(matrix.length).fill(false);

    function dfs(node, previous=-1) {
        if (visited[node]) return false; // cycle
        visited[node] = true;
        const neighbors = matrix[node];
        for (let neighbor = 0; neighbor < neighbors.length; neighbor++) {
            if (neighbor != previous && neighbors[neighbor] && !dfs(neighbor, node)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // When no cycles were found and all nodes were reachable from node 0 => tree!
    return dfs(0) && !visited.includes(false);
}

function findHeaviestPathFrom(adj, node, previous=-1) {
    const neighbors = adj[node];
    let heaviest = {
        nodes: [],
        weight: 0
    };
    for (let neighbor of neighbors) {
        if (neighbor != previous) {
            const path = findHeaviestPathFrom(adj, neighbor, node);
            if (path.weight > heaviest.weight) heaviest = path;
        }
    }
    heaviest.nodes.push(node);
    heaviest.weight += neighbors.length - (previous !== -1)    
    return heaviest;
}

function findHeaviestPath(matrix) {
    // Turn the matrix into an adjacency list
    let adj = matrix.map(row => row.map((isEdge, i) => isEdge ? i : -1).filter(i => i > -1));
    // Find the node that has the heaviest connection to node 0
    let remote = findHeaviestPathFrom(adj, 0).nodes[0];
    // Find heaviest path starting in that node
    return findHeaviestPathFrom(adj, remote);
}

const matrix = [
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

if (!isUndirected(matrix)) console.log("The graph is directed");
else if (!isTree(matrix)) console.log("The graph is not a tree");
else console.log("Heaviest path: ", JSON.stringify(findHeaviestPath(matrix)));
```